# How to prolong time of displaying of images in carousel slideshow

Tags: theming, 8

I use Bootstrap 3-based Drupal 8 theme ([Jethro](https://www.drupal.org/project/jethro)). In the header, I have carousel of sliding images. They change every 5 seconds. I'd like to prolong this time to e.g. 30 seconds, so that every image is displayed for 30 seconds, not 5. So far I found only [how to change speed of the change, animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332431/how-can-i-control-the-speed-that-bootstrap-carousel-slides-in-items), which is not the task. Any idea how to do it?

## What I tried

In `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css`:

```
.carousel-inner .item {
  ...
  transition: 30s ease-in-out left; # Increase time here
  } # Together with below it makes sliding slower, nothing more
```

and in `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.min.js`:

```
this.interval = 50000 // It does nothing
interval: 5000 * 10 // In Carousel.DEFAULTS; it makes sliding slower
```

Comment: how does the carousel get created? can you modify the html output? just add `data-interval="30000"` to the `.carousel` element and it should be 30 seconds :)

Comment: what exactly did you try ?  can you write down what did you try ?

Comment: @Alex: It uses `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.css`... I can modify these files or `main.css`, but nowhere I find `data-interval`. Should I add it to `.carousel-inner .item {...}`? @zhilevan: Added.

Comment: This seems like a bootstrap specific question.

Comment: @Kevin: Bootstrap seems to be the most common base to make themes in Drupal 8. I don't know how much use bootstrap to be modified to work well in Drupal...

Comment: Thats what I mean - it sounds like someone versed in Bootstrap might be able to point you to a way to overload that object with your own settings (since it is in `bootstrap.js`). Is the carousel a Drupal behavior or object?

Comment: guys - youre heading in the wrong direction. it is a drupal specific question because how you change the interval depends on how you output the carousel. it is clear that is has to be done via `data-` attribute (if possible) or custom js. do you use a view? is the field output a drupal carousel? what does the carousel come from? plain html? DONT change the bootstrap source files. the interval has nothing to do with css. just answer the question on where the carousel comes from and we can help you further

Comment: @Alex: How can I find it out? It is not a view, it is not available in blocks. What do You mean by "drupal carousel"? I _think_ it comes from bootstrap defaults (i.e. I didn't find any existing time control in the Jethro theme).

Comment: @Tilia sorry but you have to at least tell me where the carousel comes from - how am i supposed to know? is it just plain html in the node maybe? i am not talking about where the bootstrap files come from. i mean where does the html code come from where the slides (the carousel itself) come from

Comment: @Alex: Obviously, it takes `templates/page.html.twig` as it contains `myCarousel` `DIV`. Inserting `data-interval="50000"` does the trick. Thank You for pointing to be able to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing with [w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) ([specifically line `<div id="myCarousel"...`](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h)) - inserting `data-interval="30000"` there (the line then looks like `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="30000">`) does the trick.

In the Jethro theme (and probably in any similar case), this backbone is in the file `templates/page.html.twig` (in version 2.0 line 85). So that inserting `data-interval="30000"` there does the trick. The line then looks like `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="30000">`. Might be this is not the most elegant way, but it works well.